# Restrict button's clickable area

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, checkbox

I have the following checkbox with a class on it, for future use

```
.class{onClick: "doSomething()"}= check_box @var, :var
```

But there's a problem. Let's pretend |AAAA| is the buton, if i click on the ==.. it still triggers doSomething().

```
|AAAA| ====================
```

I tryied with

```
display: block
```

in css but it doesn't work

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because both the label and input area are enclosed in the `.class`.

Instead, specify via js that you only want the checkbox input to trigger your JS action, and not the label.

`= check_box @var, :var, id: 'my-id'`

Then:

```
:javascript

   $("input#my-id").click(function() {
       doSomething();
   });
```

Answer (score 1):

What is generated html?

Looks like you've set `onClick` handler to outer `div`, not to the checkbox.

( I assume you have reasons to use inline javascript instead on unobtrusive one)

Answer (score 1):

There may be 2 reasons this:

1: You have a label tag around the checkbox as well as element containing ==================== (As you said in the question )

2: You may not have given the class to checkbox, rather it is bound to another element that contains checkbox.